# PackageMaker "Result of Script" requirement never passes

Tags: packagemaker

I am trying to use the "Result of Script" Requirement to check if a particular process is running, so that I can message the user before installation begins.
My script is a shell script that returns 1 for failure and 0 for success. The problem I'm having is that, regardless of my return value, the installer flow is interpreting it as failure. I am not using an incredibly simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "script starting">> /tmp/myfile
true
```

(the echo is to assure myself that the script is, in fact, running). I've tried replacing the last line with a lot of things (exit 0, exit 1, "true", "TRUE") but nothing results in the test passing.

I also discovered the following JavaScript code that gets added to distribution.dist when I activate this requirement.

```
<installation-check script="pm_install_check();"/>
<script>function pm_install_check() {
    if(!(system.run('path/to/script/myscript.sh') == true)) {
        my.result.title = 'Title';
        my.result.message = 'Message';
        my.result.type = 'Fatal';
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
```

as far as i can tell, the expression in the if statement will never evaluate to true. So, I'm assuming this is my problem. I don't know how to get around it, though, because this code is generated by PackageMaker.

## Update

I've decided to work under the impression that this is a bug in PackageMaker, and am close to a workaround. Rather than using the "Result of Script" requirement, I used the "Result of Javascript" requirement, and built a Javascript function the looks like

```
function my_check() {
    code = system.run('path/to/script/myscript.sh');
    return code == 0;
}
```

Now my only problem is that this will only work when I point to my script via an absolute path. Obviously this poses a problem for an installer.

Answer (score 7):

It's probably too late for you but I feel like this should be documented somewhere.

I'd been looking around for an answer for this for most of this morning. Long story short I ended up looking at generic bash scripting and I found some info about returning values from a script called by a script. Here's how it can be done:

Anywhere you'd be using `exit 0` (for success) use `$(exit 1)`.

As you'd expect `exit 1` should be replaced by `$(exit 0)`.

I realize that it's backwards and I don't really get the reasoning behind it but after some experimentation that's what I found.

Comment: Thanks Kevin! It is too late for me :-) but I hope this can help someone else, as it is certainly not intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this isn't exactly an answer to the question, but it did end up being a solution to my problem. This freeware packaging utility called [Packages](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html) supports the "Result of Script" functionality and handles the path correctly. Unfortunately the packages it creates are only compatible with OS 10.5 and later. To support 10.4, I'm building a separate installer using PackageMaker but skipping the "Result of Script" requirement.