# PackageMaker - result of script always failes

Tags: perl, packagemaker

I added a script to the package maker - under Distribution->Requirements. The problem I have is the script result is always false (at least from the installer prospective). I have simplified my script below. Even this script fails? I've executed this command from terminal and the return value is zero as expected.

I'm using verion 3.04 of package maker.

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl -w
 use strict;
 exit 0;
```

I've tried returning 1 as well but the result is always the same.

Anyone have success with a requirement script and package maker?

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/257811/105002

Comment: That link does not address my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to use a perl script?
If not, you can use a shell script. I use it and it works.

```
#!/bin/sh  
#do your stuff  
exit 0
```

You can get some more info at [Scripting in Packagemaker](http://macinstallers.blogspot.in/2012/07/scripting-in-installer-packages.html)

Comment: I get the same results using shell or perl. I ran some additional tests and have determined that the script is never executed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the script doesn't get evaluated? I also added a script to the requirements list and got weird results. What I found in another article on StackOverflow was, that the return value is just interpreted in an unexpected way. Here's the article:

[PackageMaker "Result of Script" requirement never passes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346446/packagemaker-result-of-script-requirement-never-passes)

This solved the problem for me. Hope it helps!